# Xamarin Forms Picker SelectedItem Binding

Tags: xamarin.forms

The Xamarin Forms doc [`Xamarin.Forms.Picker.SelectedItem`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Picker.SelectedItem) says there is a public property `SelectedItem` for `Picker`.  However, I get an error when I try to bind to it. The picker is not very useful if you have to manually handle the `SelectedIndex` property.

Tony

Comment: Which version of Xamarin.Forms are you using? Bindable picker exists in [2.3.4 only](https://blog.xamarin.com/new-xamarin-forms-pre-release-2-3-4-pre1-quality-improvements-bindable-picker/)

Comment: Make sure that the type of VM property used to bind to `SelectedItem` is same as that of the type used in `ItemsSource` collection.

Answer (score 11):

No need to manually handle the `SelectedIndex`. You can use the `Picker`'s `SelectedItem` property. Just make sure your types are the same. For example, if your `ItemsSource` is bound to a property:

```
BookTitles List<string> { get; set; }
```

your `SelectedItem` has to be something like:

```
SelectedBookTitle string { get; set; }
```

Make sure to set the `SelectedBookTitle` value to show a title when the page is first shown.
Do not forget to set `Mode` to `TwoWay` on the `SelectedItem Binding`.
for example:

```
<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding BookTitles}" SelectedItem="{Binding 
SelectedBookTitle, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

This will ensure the title is shown when the page is first displayed,
and keeps the value of `SelectedBookTitle` equal on the Page and codebehind/viewmodel.

No need to use behaviours in this example.

Answer (score 4):

You can add this feature relatively easy, even with older versions of Forms pre 2.3.4 which supports it out of the box. Just create a custom [behaviour](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/behaviors/) to bind the picker items. You can implement your own version or use an existing library, like the Xamarin University Infrastructure Library which is available as [source](https://github.com/xamarinhq/xamu-infrastructure) and as a [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XamarinUniversity.Infrastructure/)

The detailed [documentation](https://github.com/xamarinhq/xamu-infrastructure/wiki/PickerBindBehavior) shows how to use it:

```
<Picker ...>
   <Picker.Behaviors>
      <inf:PickerBindBehavior Items="{Binding Colors}" 
                          SelectedItem="{Binding FavoriteColor}" />
   </Picker.Behaviors>
</Picker>
```

The approach of the behaviour is to expose a bindable property (the items) and use an observable collection. Whenever that changes, the behaviour updates the items of the picker.